# Is there a difference between using self in instance_eval block for method definition?

Tags: ruby

Given that self refers to the object in which instance_eval was invoked on, is there a difference between using self in instance_eval block for method definition?

```
Z.instance_eval do
  def x
  end

  def self.y
  end
end

> Z.x
 => nil 
> Z.y
 => nil
```

self seems superfluous given that self refers to Z.

Comment: [This](https://blog.yugui.jp/entry/846) may help. It is written by one of the Ruby core developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference. For precisely the reason you explained in the question.

This is an example of a *redundant use of `self`*. It's more common to see this when invoking a method, rather than defining it:

```
class Donald
  def x
  end

  def y
    self.x # <-- `self` is redundant. We could just call `x` directly.
  end
end
```

However, if you'll excuse the absurdity of my example, being able to explicitly state the object (even if it's `self`) can sometimes be useful. Consider:

```
class Y; end

class Z; end

Z.instance_eval do
  def random_class
    rand > 0.5 ? Y : self
  end

  def random_class.x
  end
end
```

Here, the `random_class` is evaluated at runtime - so the code is syntactically valid, even though the `self` may be superfluous.